# Independently select reference and date using Regex for parsing text

Tags: regex, regex-group, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am parsing text in Power Automate in a multi line pdf document.
The text example is like the one below

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Invoice Nº / Date
12345678 / 10.04.2023
```

Using Google, Stack Overflow and regex101 I got this far:

```
(?<=Invoice Nº / Date\r|Invoice Nº / Date\n)[^\r\n]+
```

that gets me this (am I that far from the intended result? please help

```
12345678 / 10.04.2023
```

how can I independently obtain the Invoice Nº and the Date to populate Excel rows?

FYI, I can't use `\K`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to match both in a single regex, use [`\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}|\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/3cNOjt/1).

Comment: because there are other lines with dates above these ones (this belongs to a multi line pdf) your suggestion will obtain a date above the reference that I am requesting.
Also I want to obtain both results independently. IE, one regex for the reference that belongs to the Invoice Nº and the date that belongs to the date

Comment: You can add some lookbehind assertions then: [`(?<=Invoice Nº \/ Date\r?\n)\d+|(?<=Invoice Nº \/ Date\r?\n\d+ \/ )\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}`](https://regex101.com/r/3cNOjt/2)

Comment: I don't use Power Automate, so I'm not exactly sure how it handles the matching part. The regex recommended above has two parts: before and after the `|`; this means that you may also match each part independently.

Comment: this was perfect, I can know retrieve the parts I require independently..
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class to handle varying line endings:

```
(?<=Invoice Nº / Date[\r\n])[^\r\n]+
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/9arlk69Zp72oYg).

To capture the parts as groups:

```
(?<=Invoice Nº \/ Date[\r\n])(\S+) \/ (\S+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/YxKsGDCHpgyCIV).

Answer (score 0):

answer provided in InSync's 2nd comment.
thank you very much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfOPg.png)